# Meteor handlebars template how to eval parameters

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a participant being rendered in this template:

```
<template name="participant">
    <div class="animated fadeIn">
      <a href="{{pathFor 'participants'}}">← Back</a>
      {{#with participant}}
        <div class="participant">
          <h3>{{fullname}}</h3>
            <dl>
                <dt>E-mail</dt>
                <dd>{{email}}</dd>
                <dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>{{tel}}</dd>
                <dt>City</dt>
                <dd>{{zip}} {{city}}</dd>
                <dt>Creation time</dt>
                <dd>added {{created_on}}</dd>

            </dl>
            {{>quickfield name="email" value=email}}
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h5><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></h5>
        </div>
      {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Where Quickfield template is:

```
<template name="quickfield">
    <input id="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

I would like to skip the second parameter, called "value", in the template call, as it is the same as the name parameters. We should be able to build the template with only one parameter.

Ideally, I should have this:

```
{{>quickfield name="email"}}
<template name="quickfield">
    <input id="{{name}}" value="{{eval('this.' + name)}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

But that doesn't work. How can I do?

Thks!

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Why cannot you just use `id="{{name}}" value="{{name}}"`?

Comment: because name is the string "email" and value should be the email of the participant "info@foo.com".

Comment: Got it now. Yeah, Spacebars are pretty limited in what they understand, but thankfully you can make almost anything with the right helpers. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional helper:

```
UI.registerHelper('get', function(name) {
  return this[name];
});
```

Now you can rewrite your template as:

```
<template name="quickfield">
  <input id="{{name}}" value="{{get name}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

Comment: Note that I'm not sure if that's 100% exactly how the `get` helper should look like, but something along those lines would do.

Comment: Thanks for this input. It's going the right direction but it still not working. I know why but I don't know how to fix it... Actually, it seems that when I add the name parameter to my template call, it looses the context (the this becomes the entire window). I've been searching quite a while but I don't understand why it is so.