# Meteor looses data context when adding a parameter to a subtemplate

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have this page:

```
<template name="participant">
      {{#with participant}}
        <div class="participant">
          <h3>{{fullname}}</h3>
            <dl>
                <dt>E-mail</dt>
                <dd>{{email}}</dd>
                <dt>Phone</dt>
                <dd>{{tel}}</dd>
                <dt>City</dt>
                <dd>{{zip}} {{city}}</dd>
                <dt>Creation time</dt>
                <dd>added {{created_on}}</dd>
            </dl>
            {{>quickfield}}
        </div>
      {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="quickfield">
    <input id="{{email}}" value="{{email}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

And it is working fine.

Now if I want to add a parameter to my quickfield subtemplate and do this:

```
{{>quickfield name="foo"}}
<template name="quickfield">
    <input id="{{name}}" value="{{email}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

the data context is lost (before, this = participant, after, this=Window). the {{email}} doesn't render anymore.

Why this, what's the workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can access the parent context:

```
<template name="quickfield">
  <input id="{{name}}" value="{{../email}}" class="bound">
</template>
```

Comment: It probably won't solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199949/) issue, though.

Comment: Yes this is a nice workaround but I need access to the entire data context of the parent because I use it in an event then...

Comment: No, because I loose my local variable when doing so.